# Use Chrome Devtools CSS Grid inspector for remote webview

Tags: android, css, google-chrome-devtools, android-webview, css-grid

I debug a Android webview using chrome devtools.
On local pages, the grid inspector works as expected, but for the webview, nothing changes when I enabled the Grid button.
Does anybody know if and then how I can use the CSS Grid Inspector on Webviews?

Chrome version: 90, on osX 11.3, Android 10 (Huawei Mate 20 Pro)